Can a stotra or a Sahasranama be chanted in some other language?

The shiva mahimna stotra and shiva Sahasranama is usually present in Hindi in the Internet. I have one book which has many stotras related to lord shiva but all in Bengali. It also has the shiva Sahasranama and the mahimna stotra in Bengali.
If I chant these in Bengali and not in Hindi will I get any effective results or is it better to chant in Hindi ?
For example in the above picture I have posted a short segment of the shiva Sahasranama in Bengali .
Will it give the same results if otherwise chanted in Hindi?
Is there any commentary which particularly deals with this language problems

You are not chanting in another language though, this is still sanskrit just transliterated into another language.
No problems, as long as the transliteration is accurate.
Just to add more to my answer: For the longest time Sanskrit didn't have a script. All the Veds, Purans, Itihaas were all nothing but "shruti" .
So what script you use to learn/memorize the sholkas are immaterial, what matters is that you understand the meaning of the words and learn to use the right pronounciation.
